# writing makefile to compile a particular module

Tags: c, makefile

I have have four files `a.c b.c c_arm.c` and header file `header.h`
I have written a make file, but when do just `make` and execute the binary it should print `I am in c-arm` but when i do `make ARM=arch` and when i execute the final binary file, it should print `I am in c-armx86`

But in my case it always prints `I am in c-arm`

Can you please tell how to write a make file do achieve the above things, here are my files

```
a.c

#include "header.h"
int main () {
   call_b();
}
```

---

```
b.c

#include "header.h"

void call_b()    {
#ifdef ARCH
  carmx86();
#else
  carm();
#endif
}
```

---

```
c_arm.c

#include "header.h"
carm() {
    printf ("I am in c-arm\n");
}
```

---

```
c_armx86.c

#include "header.h"
void carmx86() {
    printf( "I am in c-armx86 \n" );
}
```

---

```
Makefile 

all: a.o b.o c_arm.o c_armx86.o
  gcc -o output a.o b.o c_arm.o c_armx86.o

a.o: a.c
  gcc -c a.c

b.o: b.c
  gcc -c b.c

c_arm.o: c_arm.c
  gcc -c c_arm.c

c_armx86.o: c_armx86.c
  gcc -c c_armx86.c

clean:
  rm *.o output
```

when i say make `ARCH=arm` it should print I am in c-armx86, if i just do a make and execute binary it should print I am in c-arm

can anyone tell how can i do this ?

Comment: @Orbit oops.. slip of finger.. :)

Comment: OK I added a blank header.h so it didn't 'make' a difference. No more C jokes, I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass -D ARCH=arm to compiler i.e.:

```
ifdef ARCH
b.o: b.c
      gcc -D ARCH=$(ARCH) -c b.c
else
b.o: b.c
      gcc -c b.c
endif
```

or equivalent:

```
b.o: b.c
ifdef ARCH
      gcc -D ARCH=$(ARCH) -c b.c
else
      gcc -c b.c
endif
```

Comment: That worked for me :-) don't make the same mistake as me and forget to "make clean" after updating the Makefile.

Comment: @user2672165 : Now its printing only I am in c-armx86

Comment: I have updated my answer to not always define ARCH. It could be rewritten so that the conditionals are applied below one single rule.